# Repository Types

Tags: java, jcr

How many types of JCRRepository are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many implementations? Quite a few that I'm aware of (in alphabetical order):

- [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) (Java)
- [eXo](http://www.exoplatform.org/documents/exo.site/) (Java)
- [Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) (Java, the reference implementation)
- [ModeShape](http://modeshape.org) (Java)
- [Priha](http://www.priha.org/) (Java)
- [TYPO3 CR](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/show/package-typo3cr) (PHP)

Of course, each implementation has their own benefits and capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Day Software's [CRX](http://www.day.com/day/en/products/crx.html)